# Dashing vs Non-Dashing, and Stalking in General

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

In XCom:EU I tend to alert the enemy a lot and can not sneak up on them.  Thus they get the first retreat and usually the first shot starting the next round  I know there is Ghost Armor later in the game but for the early game:

- Does dashing causes more noise?  Can you stalk better if you don't dash?
- Does ground type affect detection?  Cocrete vs metal
- Does jumping over logs create noise?
- Even better does the game even factor in noise like the older games?  I know the squad can hear enemy movement.

In the other UFO/Xcom games there were stalking abilities.  Are there any skills that improve stalking in XCom:EU

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The noise mechanic in the game is about informing you of the direction of the nearest alien.  In the original x-com game, it was possible to miss an alien as you explored the map and then have to completely re-explore the map looking for it.  The noice mechanic addresses this problem and keeps the action and tension rolling.

There is no noise mechanic that alerts enemy units.  Enemy Alerting is sight only.

---

There are a number of ways you can detect enemies without alerting them.  GhostArmor, Sniper throw toy, seeing over half cover while on a higher altitude and out of line of sight.

---

As you said, if you discover aliens on your turn, that's very risky.  Aliens get a free half action to move to cover, and then a full turn before you get a full turn.  If your last guy discovers an alien, you're in for trouble.

Here's what I do to manage the risk of discovering aliens on my turn:

- the first two units I move (let's call them scouts) are allowed to uncover new areas of the map with a half move.
- If the scouts uncover way too much danger, you can move them back to safety with the second half move.  The aliens usually follow you when they have numbers.
- If there are units (such as snipers) where I would rather take a reaction shot against no cover, instead of a normal shot with cover, I put those units in overwatch **before** moving my scouts.
- If I don't uncover aliens with the scouts, the remaining forces may full move, half move and reload, or half move and overwatch as needed.  The only restriction is that they are not allowed to reveal more map.
- Scouts must have enough ammo to fire at least twice (this turn and next turn) before revealing map.  If they don't have enough ammo, half move toward safety/full cover and reload.

If you discover aliens on your turn with this approach, you'll still have 4 full actions and 2 half actions to deal with them.

Comment: Good management tips, that will help if the sniper toy doesn't find anything in one area.

Comment: The tutorial states that barging through doors and windows can create noise that alerts enemies.  In over 50 hours of playing, I've never had this happen.

Answer (score 7):

XCOM:EU does not use noise as a detection factor. You are detected by the enemy as soon as you come into their sight range, which is generally as soon as you see them. Very rarely I have been able to see an enemy before they have seen me, but as a general rule, when you see them, they see you.

Comment: I know there is also a hearing element thought, where the squad will say "Shh did you hear that" or something like that.

Comment: I guess part of my question is: Does there sight range include 360 view or can you get behind them?

Comment: @Mike - The hearing element is only on the part of the squad, as a way to help you find the enemies without having to search the entire map. Sight range is 360 degrees; you can't sneak up behind them.

Comment: I think you can abuse the sniper sight drone thing to get vision on an enemy before they see you. They don't react to the ball and the ball goes out farther than you can see.

Comment: @Shykin - That's right, I forgot about that.

Comment: I abuse it like crazy, lots of alien groups have eaten rockets to the face because of that :P.

Comment: Note: there are stages that always have the enemy in the exact same spot.  You can literally shoot a rocket or lob a grenade in the area, and it will kill something.  Also, the stage where you rescue Mr. Hutch allows you to see the Thin Men on the far right side before you alert them.